# Issues using bash script to backup bitbucket

Tags: bash, bitbucket-api

Currently we have a bash script in place that will go through bitbucket store clones of each repository on a hard drive and backup that hard drive.  Recently though the number of repositories has exceeded the bitbucket api pagelen count of 100.  I've been unable to find a better way to do this so that we can backup more than 100.

```
repositories=`curl -s -S --user <user>:<password> https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<name>\?pagelen\=100 | jq -r '.values[] | "\(.full_name)"'`

echo "backup-bitbucket STARTED -- " $(date +"%m-%d-%Y"+"%T") >> ${LOGFILE}

# Back up each bitbucket repository by cloning or pulling the latest changes
for i in $repositories
do
    echo "Starting backup for repository ${i}..." >> ${LOGFILE}

    if [ -d "${BACKUPTODIR}${i}" ]; then
            git -C ${BACKUPTODIR}${i} pull
    else
            git clone https://<user>:<password>@bitbucket.org/${i}.git ${BACKUPTODIR}${i}
    fi

    echo "Completing backup for repository ${i}..." >> ${LOGFILE}
done
```

Any help in this matter would be appreciated

Comment: try adding `&page=2` to see if you get the next 100 entries

Comment: if i edit the curl to include '\?pagelen\=100&page=2' the jq conversion doesn't happen and I get straight JSON

Comment: Check my answer, you need to add quotes around the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it on my terminal, and apprently it's possible to add the `page` option in the url.

So `&page=2` gives you the next 100 results

When you add `&page` make sure you put quotes around the URL

Comment: Thanks for the assist!